# Lock waiting in an API should it be exposed

Tags: java, api, locking

I am providing an api to do some crud operations, which inturn uses a existing internal implementation, what I have implemented additionally is a lock mechanism , which waits/retries definitely for a application level lock to do these operations, if it cannot acquire in some retries , it throws a custom Exception with the error text . During code review I was told that this waiting should not be done, instead the user of the api , should handle this.

should I remove this lock waiting from the Implementation?

```
        lockManager = new LockManager();
        aquiredLock = lockManager.aquireLock();
        final int numberOfRetries = 3;
        final int sleepTime = 1000;
        int retryAttempt = 0;
        while (!aquiredLock.isLockAquired() && retryAttempt < numberOfRetries) {
            retryAttempt++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new CannotAcquireLockException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            aquiredLock = lockManager.aquireLock();
        }
```

Regards,
Goutham

Comment: Possibly, can you try running your program without this waiting. Perhaps its not needed.

Comment: If this is a standard GUI app, one should generally not wait (for lock, network activity, or whatever) for any "substantial" time in the main GUI thread, as this "locks up" the GUI and results in very poor "human interface" behavior (and sometimes can result in the OS killing the app).  It's generally OK, though, to wait for a brief time -- less than a second.  In your code it appears you might wait 3 seconds, which is a bit on the long side.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Locking is necessary as multiple applicatons can use this api.

Comment: @HotLicks It is not called from a GUI app, this is called from backend  applicaiton to dynamically generate some objects to map there already existing objects, I agree with you regarding the locking time, may be that should be a configurable parameter

Comment: @flash I understand the need for locking, but is there a need for *waiting*?

Comment: If it's not a GUI app/thread, lock away!  There's certainly nothing wrong conceptually with using locks (and waiting for them).  It's done all the time in big iron applications.  (Though if it were me I'd probably wait in smaller increments -- say 100ms.)

Comment: @PeterLawrey -- Without waiting, how do you ever get the lock?  Granted, there are (in other languages) better (more granular) ways to wait than shown above, but Java has a rather limited set of primitives for locks, so I'm not sure there's a better way for this case.

Comment: @HotLicks The `lockManager.aquireLock()` method appears to be like `Lock.tryLock()` which only locks if it can which is why polling it does anything at all ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey -- Yeah, LockManager is not a Java 5 class, so I'm unsure of the function of the method.  But, looking at the specs, `Lock.tryLock(time,unit)` would apparently work better here -- requiring no loop.

Comment: (And if LockManager is a class defined by the user, it should include a tryLock type method that encapsulates the above logic into a single tidy call.)

Answer (score 3):

This kind of thing cannot be decided in general. Your code reviewers probably know a lot about your problem domain, so their advice may well be justified.

From a general perspective I can only say that the kind of code you are showing would definitely not be the default/obvious way to do it and would be called for only when it is clear from the circumstances that this approach is indeed necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Its your choice, depending on what API you whant to provide, for me there is this alternative

- You leave the lock waiting mechanism in your method. **Benefits**: easier for the user since it does not have to care about this lock problem. **Drawback**: the API user cannot act to timeout or retry himself.
- If you just try to acquire the lock and throw if you could not. **Benefits**: the user can decide itself for a retry/timeout strategy.

In both case you have to document your choice in your API. What is important in the review process is that it can tell you if this choice is consistent with other parts of the API (other methods regarding the same locks), and if this lock is really needed.

Side note: in our application (database engine), we provide the API to acquire/release the locks and tests in API calls that the locks are indeed held.